# Python proxy - Need help to send HTTP header to the browser

Tags: python, http-proxy

I'm making a proxy for my project and I'm trying to send to the browser (Firefox) an HTTP header to continue the "Conversation" between me(Proxy server) and the browser. The issue is: when I'm refreshing any page, the page Keeping loading. I use socket and select for the proxy:

```
import socket, select

#Sending a message for the waiting list
def send_Waiting_Messages(wlist):
    for msg in messages_to_send:
        clientSocket, data = msg
        if clientSocket in wlist:
            clientSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
            messages_to_send.remove(msg)

serverSocket = socket.socket()
serverSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0',8080))
serverSocket.listen(10)
open_client_sockets = []
messages_to_send = []

while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([serverSocket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])
    for currentSocket in rlist:
        if currentSocket is serverSocket:
            newSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
            open_client_sockets.append(newSocket)
        else:
            data = currentSocket.recv(1024)
            if data == "":
                open_client_sockets.remove(currentSocket)
                print 'Conn is closed'
            else:
                print data
                messages_to_send.append((currentSocket, 'Hello, ' + data))
    send_Waiting_Messages(wlist)
```

These lines:

```
clientSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n')
clientSocket.send('Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
```

are for sending the header.

Thanks for helpers!!

Comment: so, what is the problem?

Comment: The page is keeping loading

Comment: I want that the page will response me again and it doesn't work because of this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice that every the `send_Waiting_Messages` function is sending the same response to all of your connected clients. I reccomend to replace it with the basic send function when the socket is in the `wlist`.

---

**This will probably work**

```
import socket, select
serverSocket = socket.socket()
serverSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0',8080))
serverSocket.listen(10)
open_client_sockets = []

while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([serverSocket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])
    for currentSocket in rlist:
        if currentSocket is serverSocket:
            newSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
            open_client_sockets.append(newSocket)
        else:
            data = currentSocket.recv(2048)
            if data == "":
                open_client_sockets.remove(currentSocket)
                print 'Conn is closed'
            else:
                print data
                content_to_send = "The content that you want to send"
                currentSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length:"+str(len(content_to_send))+"\r\n\r\n"+content_to_send)
```

Comment: Try to define content_to_send in the beginning of the code.